# Getting empty object in web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, erc-20, authentication

I have a user registeration logic defined in solidity which used to work fine when I set an registeration fees of 0.5 ETH for testing purpose.But now, when I remove the register fees, I'm not able to register any user, instead I get an empty object in console.

```
c {}__proto__
: constructor: ƒ c()
    arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.o (<anonymous>:1:83)]caller: (...)length: 0name: "c"prototype: {constructor: ƒ}__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: index.js:35[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]__proto__: Object'
   length: 0,
    name: "c"
```

> *Web3js*

```
async function userRegisterationn() {
       var input = $("#refer_id").val();
        
        let ref = web3.utils.isAddress($("#refer_id").val());
        if (ref) {
            contract.methods
            .isUserExists(account)
            .call()
            .then((isUserExist) => {
                console.log(account);
                if (isUserExist) {
                
                  $(".success_tx").hide();
                  $(".tx").show();
                  $(".transaction_err").text("Already Registered");
                  console.log("Already exists");
                  return false;
                } else if(isUserExist == false) {
                    
                let referral = $("#refer_id").val();
                contract.methods
                    .registeration(referral)
                    .call()
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(res)
                        if (res) {
                            localStorage.setItem("user_address", account);
                            $(".tx").hide();
                            $(".success_message").text("User Registered Successfully");
                            $(".success_tx").show();
                            window.location.href = "users/index.php";
                        }                   
                }
            })
        }
    }
 }
```

> *Solidity*

```
struct User {
    uint id;
    address referrer;
    uint partnerCount;
    bool isRegistered;
}

uint public lastUserId = 2;

mapping(address => User) public users;

 function isUserExists(address _userAddress)  public view returns(bool) {
    // return users[_userAddress].id != 0;
    return users[_userAddress].isRegistered;
}

function registeration(address _referAddress) external  {
    userRegisteration(msg.sender, _referAddress);
}

function userRegisteration(address _userAddress, address _referAddress) internal returns(bool) {
    // require(msg.value == 0.05 ether, 'registeration cost 0.05');
    if(users[_userAddress].isRegistered == true) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if(users[_referAddress].isRegistered == false) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // require(!isUserExists(_userAddress), "User already exists");
    // require(isUserExists(_referAddress), "Referrer doesn't exist");
    // uint32 size;
 
    User memory user = User({
        id: lastUserId,
        referrer: _referAddress,
        partnerCount: 0,
        isRegistered: true
    });
    
    users[_userAddress] = user;
    users[_userAddress].referrer = _referAddress;
    users[_referAddress].partnerCount++;
    
    lastUserId++;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please don't dump your entire front-end code here. Specify only the relevant code (e.g., whatever gives you the error-message given at the top of your question).

Comment: @goodvibration Done so, Thank you for pointing that..!

Comment: To begin with, you need to change `registeration(referral).call()` to  `registeration(referral).send()`.

Comment: I guess, we use send when we want to send transaction or want to pay some ether..But in this case, I don't want to send any ether...Pardon me if i'm wrong..

Comment: You've specified two things - 'send a transaction' and 'pay some ether'. Then, you're saying that you don't want to do one of them. So here's a small question - what option do we have left?

Comment: Basically, I want to register user on the blockchain..I did that before but with 0.5 register fees..But now I want to register user free of cost and when trying to do, it gave me an empty object..I guess, for writting data to the blockchain, we should use send method in web3js..should we ??

Comment: `call` and `send` aren't there in order to distinguish between yes/no eth-transfer. They are there in order to distinguish between calling a constant (pure or view) function, designated just for retrieving information from the blockchain (where no mining is required and therefore no gas-fee applies), and executing a non-constant function which changes the state of the blockchain (thus, mining IS required and gas-fee DOES apply).

Comment: So, I have an internal function in this case and required data to be stored in the blockchain..which one should I use ??

Comment: What does the internal function have to do with all of this??? I told you that when you want to execute a non-constant function, you need to do it as a transaction (i.e., by using `send`).

Comment: is there any alternative way to identify user authentication and register user on blockchain without any fees..Because I don't want any registeration fees...

Comment: What does 'register user on blockchain' mean???

Comment: if you see my code above, I have a struct name users which stores the user on blockchain and isUserExists function for verifying the user, but it takes some gas amount to store data to the blockchain..This is working great, but what I want is to have user authentication but without any fees...

Comment: You cannot change the blockchain without paying gas.

Comment: I saw a dapp using User Authentication locally..how can they do that ?? is it possible using backend language like PHP, java with Smart contract

Comment: Yes, but what has that got to do with paying gas fee??? You'd have to pay gas regardless of what language you're using in order to interact with the blockchain. And that Dapp you saw - if it executes transactions on the blockchain (i.e., if it changes the blockchain), then it pays gas!

Comment: No, I don't think the dapp I'm talking about use registeration part on the blockchain..Because there isn't any structure or array named users..What they do is using metamask or trust wallet for connecting user wallet to their Dapp..When it connects successfully, what they do is, redirect user to the main page...So I guess they are using one of the backend language for the registeration...aren't they?? Now the question that I wonder, how would they do that...?

Comment: I don't know what they do, but that question has nothing to do with Ethereum.

Comment: May be I should ask new question regarding that...Thank you for your support

Comment: If they execute transactions on the blockchain, then they do so either using their own private key (paying gas out of their own account), or using the unlocked accounts of their users (paying gas out of their users' accounts).

Comment: Nope, I don't think so...Firstly they don't have any user structure or any thing related to user in smart contract.

Comment: If they don't execute anything on the blockchain, then this question is surely not related to Ethereum.